# piping command to wsl awk doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, powershell, ubuntu-20.04, wsl2

I'm running Windows 10 / WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04 and am trying to do `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2 }'` in PowerShell. Here's what I've come up with:

```
wsl ifconfig eth0 | wsl grep 'inet ' | wsl awk '{ print $2 }'
```

`wsl grep` works in PowerShell as `grep` does in Ubuntu but `wsl awk` does not work in PowerShell as `awk` works in Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send your entire command to WSL once as one big bash command instead of 3 separate WSL calls, like:

```
wsl bash -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print \`$2 }'"
```

Comment: The output still isn't matching. `wsl bash -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '"` matches `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '` on Ubuntu BUT `wsl bash -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2 }'"` matches `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '` - not `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2 }`..

Comment: You are correct @neubert, my original answer did not work. It needed some additional powershell escape characters around the $2. Edited my answer, which should work as-is now

Answer (score 2):

It seems an issue about the escape characters for the special character "$", the variable's prefix character.

In windows CMD wsl, caret([^]) works well for escaping special character in many cases. For your example,

```
C:\Users\Administrator> wsl ifconfig eth0 | wsl grep 'inet ' | wsl awk '{ print ^$2 }'
```

In windows Powershell, backslash([\]) and backquotation([`]) and some characters works for escaping special character case by case.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wsl ifconfig eth0 | wsl grep 'inet ' | wsl awk '{ print \$2 }'
```

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wsl bash -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print \`$2 }'"
```

In bash shell, backslash([\]) works too.

```
me@Leno:/mnt/c/Users/Administrator$ bash -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
```